# How to use Reference with 3rd party dependencies within two projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

When using a project reference, how can i make sure all 3rd party references from my reference will add to my main project.

**In my case I've two projects**

1. Main project (console .net 4.7)
2. dotnet standard project (library), depending a RestSharp NuGet.

a. What is the correct way to use project No.2 as a reference for project No.1 ?
b. How can i make sure project No.1 will reference RestSharp dependency ?

Comment: Not sure what you are after. You just add the reference to your project and it will work. To have direct reference to RestSharp you need to add it from nuget - here there is a bit of manual effort while managing dependencies as you should have them in single version across whole project. That includes other third party libs that you want and their dependencies.

Comment: do i have to add restsharp manualy to the main project ?

Comment: For all new projects based on .NET Core SDK, dependencies are transitive, https://www.erikheemskerk.nl/transitive-nuget-dependencies-net-core-got-your-back/ For legacy projects, you might have to manually add the references. The C# compiler is smart enough to give you errors.